# Como instalar apache 2.2.31 no fedora?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, servidor

Preciso fazer manutenção em um site que só roda com essa configuração:

- Apache: 2.2.31
- php: 5.4.45
- mysql: 5.5.50-cll

Estou tentando configurar no fedora23, já removi td relacionado ao apache que estava instalado e tentei instalar novamente seguindo a instruções no próprio site do apache, porem ele acaba instalando a versão mais recente ou me devolve erros de repositórios

Comment: Só lembrando, a versão 23 do Fedora não usa mais o yum. É o dnf

Comment: a versão que preciso não esta disponível, testei com yum e dnf, com yum ele converte o comando pra dnf e executa!! será que eu preciso inserir alguma repositório ?